# How does PHP, HTML and CSS fit together?

Tags: php, html

I have left the programming world for like 15 years, and previously dealing in C++. So take me as a complete newbie. Would you give a brief explanation for me?

- HTML - just a "holder"
- CSS - to set the formatting of this "holder"
- JavaScript - to add effects to the contents in html
- PHP - programming logic (where statements and inputs are tested etc)

I'm looking to build a site with a login. Am I correct in understanding this?

HTML Form - user enters id/password, then goes to a PHP file to connect to database and validate login.

They then redirects to the main user interface (do I keep the DB connection open?)

Users do whatever they want, and then logout (database connection close). Or what should be the way to do a simple login system?

Another question to help me understand php syntax better

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

Is `$email` a self-defined variable created in the PHP? Is `test_input()` is a self-defined function name? Where does the `$emailErr` come from? (is it a PHP feature where variable gets an error, the syntax is variablename+Err?)

Comment: HTML is a document markup language - it describes the structure of your pages. JavaScript is a programming language that (in the context you describe it) is run on the browser. It is often used for screen effects but it can do a lot of things, like send data to the server, control your webcam, or read/write from a database. PHP is a programming language that is run on the server.

Comment: Yes, `$email` and `$emailErr` are self-defined variables. `test_input()` is a self-defined function, or is supplied by a library - it is not part of PHP. Variables do not "get an error" - you can see that `$emailErr` has been explicitly assigned inside the `if()` block.

Comment: Your questions are rather broad at present. That's fine in itself, but the question and answer format here does not really lend itself to discursive introductions. Have you undertaken some tutorials? I have a comprehensive one for PHP in my profile - take a look to see if it is of interest.

Comment: Database connections are not kept open per user for the duration of their logon-logoff session. They are opened for each page rendering and closed at the end. Session cookies stored by the browser help the web server remember who is who.

Answer (score 1):

On the browser side everything is structured around the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). The DOM is a *tree structure* (think folders and files) which describes the structure of your document. Each "thing" in your document is an element in the DOM tree somewhere.

HTML is a way to describe this DOM structure.
CSS is a declarative way to apply style attributes to this DOM structure.
Javascript is a programmatic way to manipulate *anything* about this DOM structure.

A server side language (like PHP) is used to answer HTTP requests with programmatically generated HTTP responses. When opening a page, a browser makes an HTTP request to a server and does something with the response. That response can be static (same URL always returns the same "file"), or it can be programmatically generated on the fly.

Beyond this, you really need to follow tutorials and manuals to get into it. We can't possibly cover such broad questions in enough detail here to be completely helpful to you.